# Post model to an MVC ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.net application with a `[HttpGet]` for a view an ActionResult named 'Create' on a Controller called `Students`

My 'Student' is then posted to the following controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Student student)
{
    Student.Add(student);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = db.Students.Add(student);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Details(result);
    }
    return View(new CreateStudent());
}
```

**`return Details(result);`** is the line I'm interested in.

Previously I had **`RedirectToAction`** where I passed in the result. `Id` property and used a `GET` request to query a database.

But, I'm not wanting to have a URL like 'students/details/id=123' Or 'students/details/123' I want to **`Post`** my model to the controller 'students/details'

var result is a single 'Student'and my 'Details' ActionResult looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(Student student)
{
   //
}
```

but **`return Details(result);`** doesn't work, I receive an error message stating:

'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'LinkApp.Models.Student', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'LinkApp.Models.DTOs.CreateStudent'.'

But I believe this is because my URL never goes to '/Students/Details', my URL still shows '/Students/Create'

Any help is appreciated. And again, if it's not clear, please ask for any clarity

Thanks

**EDIT DUE TO ME NOT BEING VERY CLEAR ;)**

Comment: How about return View("Details", result); ? Doesn't that work?

Comment: It's still not quite clear, what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your question depends on `Details` action method which is not placed in your code!

Comment: One possibility to *simulate* a post from controller to controller would be to store your data in  `TempData` or a `dynamic` object, redirect to the view and the view calls the other controller method, that reads the  temp data.

Comment: What do you mean _Post my model to the controller 'students/details_? Your posting to `Create()`. Do you also have a `Details()` method marked with `[HtppPost]` Its unclear what your trying to do.

Comment: @thomo Can you say if what I suggested in the first comment works for you? Thank you!

Comment: If you want to POST to the `[HttpPost]Details()` method, then just change the form - `@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Student", FormMethod.Post)) { ... }`

Comment: Hi Mihai sorry forgot to mention, I had previously tried this, and the view does update to 'students/Details' but the URL stays on 'students/Create' Thank you for the response

Comment: Hi Stephen. I would like the result from Create controller to be passed after some login has been completed. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

So I'm a little bit confused with what you're trying to achieve.

Here is what I've gathered: *You want to `POST` the data. Right now you have a `GET` method. You can think of a `GET` method like something that retrieves, and a `POST` as something that gives.*

So your `GET` method should not be trying to `POST` anything.

Your `GET` method should looks like it should be a `POST` since you're trying to "give" the data to something, not *get* the data.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Student student)
    {
        Student.Add(student);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = db.Students.Add(student);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return View("Details", result);
        }

        return View(); //You should add a property to the model called ErrorMessage or something like that, then you could do student.ErrorMessage = "Model state was not valid";, then you could do return View(student); and in the view you could do something like @if (Model.ErrorMessage != null) { @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.ErrorMessage); }
    }
```

This is what your post should look like, you're saving the `Student` model to the database and returning to a view.

Now your `GET` should just be something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
return View();
}
```

**Edit:**

If you wanted your post to do the error message I left in the comment above you would just do this right above the second `return View();`

```
student.ErrorMessage = "Model state was not valid;" //Or whatever you want to say
return View(student);
```

Then in your view you would have something like this:

```
@if (student.ErrorMessage != null)
{
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ErrorMessage);
}
```

Comment: @maxshuty...I don't believe I made myself clear, the issue isn't to do with any ModelState errors, is just trying to pass a model to another ActionResult

Comment: @thomo I just added that errors because it's good practice to tell your user an error occurred. You can ignore that part.

Comment: Thanks maxshuty. I mentioned in a comment above (just now) that I have tried return View("Details", result); this, but the URL stays at 'students/create' You're absolutely right about the error handling, thanks, on my todo list! Thanks :)

Comment: @thomo Sorry just got to this message. Do you have this resolved? If you set a breakpoint at this line `if (ModelState.IsValid)` does it say `true` or `false`?